# Debugging Libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I finally got my project building in Android Studio with gradle. When I debug my project breakpoints in the "application" module work, but breakpoints inside of the "library" module don't work. Is this a bug or do I have something setup wrong?

**Update**
If I run the application and then attach the debugger it works as expect, but it still doesn't work if the app is started by clicking Debug in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I started a topic on the adt-dev Google group and Xavier says it is a problem with Android Studio.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/PhsHqkapSIQ

Comment: Any news on this?  I'm having this problem.

Comment: It was fixed a while back and I haven't had any problems since.

Comment: @respectTheCode, it seems that it's not fully fixed. I'm experiencing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27200206/android-studio-doesnt-highlight-line-in-debugger-when-hit-by-debugger). Can you please take a look to see if it's the same problem you had?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that may help someone with this. If your project is using fragments that are in the library project, then you must include the fragment in the library project manifest:

```
<activity android:name="[name of fragment]"/>
```